# Is it possible to have the OneDrive directory inside a VeraCrypt container?

Tags: windows, partitioning, onedrive, veracrypt

I created a VeraCrypt partition on my PC's disk (~40GB).

Said partition is mounted and available normally - I can create/copy/use files on it as normal.

I then installed the latest, freshly downloaded version of OneDrive and changed the location of the OneDrive folder to be inside the VeraCrypt (1.26.7) container. Quickly skipped through the tour to open the OneDrive dir for the first time.

I immediately switched Files On-Demand to On. The following error quickly appears:

```
Couldn't start Files on Demand
Please restart your computer and try again.
Error codes: 0x801f000f
```

Closing the error kills OneDrive. It isn't possible to amend Settings as this error is modal.

Subsequent restarts of OneDrive produce the error pretty much immediately (without chance to revert the Files On-Demand option).

Restarting the computer doesn't alleviate the problem. Uninstalling OneDrive and clearing the following dirs allows a cleaner reinstallation:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\OneDrive        
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow\Temp
C:\Windows\Temp
```

Attempting again - yields the same problem.

Suggestions for the error code are to reinstall...‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in my case turned out to be the file system. **VeraCrypt had defaulted to exFAT** and I didn't see a problem. **However, OneDrive wants NTFS** (but doesn't say so ).

To fix: Ensured OneDrive was killed in the Task Manager. Temporarily copied the sync'd files off the partition to somewhere else. Formatted the (mounted VeraCrypt) partition as NTFS. Copied the files back. Started OneDrive again. It did it's usual sync without the error and now I'm back in business.

I eventually realised NTFS was the probable cause from the following Reddit discussion (so hat tip to Redditors):
[Reddit r/onedrive - Onedrive "Couldn't start Files on Demand" error message](https://www.reddit.com/r/onedrive/comments/npddy6/comment/j2utqzh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button)

Hopefully this will increase visibility of this problem - it'll probably be me using it in future when I forget.

Comment: Nice one, I genuinely thought the containers wouldn't let you use external apps due to encryption. I've saved it too. Cheers.